# Android WebView - Dithering/Changes on Tap

Tags: android, webview

I am currently working on an application that requires the use of a WebView. It basically takes up the entire screen space.

Initially the images inside of the WebView look fine and high quality. Unfortunately, when a user taps (and holds) a button in the webview, the images then lose quality and dither until the finger is released. Is there any way to disable this?

A good note, my app does not need any scrolling whatsoever. I thought Android would only lower the quality on scroll to better performance.

Comment: Same here - this might only affect android prior to 4.x. I have observed that the effect is less worse when you set `setDrawingCacheQuality(View.DRAWING_CACHE_QUALITY_HIGH)` on your WebView. However, this still looks awful on OpenLayers...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the only solution is to make your own image viewer, the webview resamples images at lower qualities

Comment: The quality loss happens on tap only, and can result in a weird color loss (square patterns can appear on background images f.i.) and text font rendering artifacts.
Disabling all scrolling (in the html and in the WebView Java-side) doesn't seem to affect this behavior...

Answer (score 0):

I've been dealing with the same issue for a long while. The best solution is to split the image into several sub-images and load them altogether within the same `html` file.

The easiest and fastest solution I found is with `Adobe Photoshop`:

> 1. Open you image
> 2. Create horizontal and vertical guides
> 3. Select the Slicing tool and activate the "create slices from guides"
> 4. Save for web (I'm not using the English version, but you get what I mean)
> 5. Select your desired image format
> 6. Save, but while saving check the option "Html and images"

With this, you'll avoid dithering with any image as long as you split it into enough pieces,